# Using $list['something'] Inside <p>

Tags: php, mysql, list, echo

How would one use the mysql/php  $list['key'] inside a php echo i.e

```
echo "<p> My Text . $list[''] . </p>";
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Function `$list['']`? This is definitely not a valid PHP function name.

Comment: Explain what `$list` contains.

Comment: well i'm wanting to output something from a mysql database so its just using $list from $list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as that:

```
echo "<p> My Text $list[index] </p>";
```

N. b.: you do not use single quotes (`'`) for the index as you usually would, like in `$a=$list['index'];`, since the whole thing is already enclosed in double quotes (`"`).

**Correction:** 
Just found out, with indices like 'a b' you still *do* need the quotes! (Thanks, Jon!)

**Edit:** (response to comment)

That is a *competely different thing*! Use

```
list($var1,$var2) = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

instead. The `list()`-construct (*is it a function?!?*) extracts the values out of the assigned array (in your case the result of your `mysql_fetch_assoc()`-function).  Assuming, that your result set returns values for two columns (otherwise you will have to supply more variables in `list()`). And then place the variables into your text like

```
echo "<p> My Text $var1 and somewhere maybe also $var2 ... </p>";
```

Still, since you are using `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` you could do

```
$z=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<p> My Text $z[field1] and somewhere maybe also $z[field2] ... </p>";
```

with `field1` and `field2` being the actual column names from your MySQL table.

It is *customary* on this site now, to also warn you of the dangers of still using the deprecated `mysql_*`functions. You should change to the more secure and modern versions of `mysqli_*`...

Comment: Depends on the index.

Comment: i get errors when trying to use it thought. Would it help to mention im using $list to draw out mysql from $list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

Comment: @user2685681 It would actually help if you showed the errors its making.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, usually you would just write the bare array key between the angle brackets:

```
echo "$array[key]";
```

However, if `key` is the empty string or if it contains any of a class of characters that have special meaning in this context then you can't do this. For example, these will not work:

```
echo "$array[]"; // empty string key
echo "$array[]]"; // string key: "]"
```

In this case you can add `{}` around the variable and use single quotes as if you were not inside a double quoted string context. For example:

```
echo "{$array['']}";
echo "{$array[']']}";
```

This is called *complex string variable parsing*; see the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) for more information.